# Adding LOAD MORE on a page

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, customization, ajax, pages

So I have a blog with different pages and categories and I add each post manually and link it with the URL instead of using post grid. I only want to show 10 posts at a time and add LOAD MORE text which will expand the page and show next 10 posts and so on, but I'm struggling to find a plunging for it any ideas?

Comment: Plugin recommendations are off topic here... ...if you want to build it yourself you can check this out and if you get stuck at any point post a new question here and someone will help:  https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/load-more-posts-ajax.html

Answer (score 0):

Check this tutorial to perform this task.
Url - https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-display-recent-posts-from-a-specific-category-in-wordpress/